# Exercise in stochastic analysis

Tags: stochastic-analysis

The problem comes from Karatzas's book 'Brownian motion and stochastic analysis'. Exercise 5.20.

Suppose $X$ is in the space of square integrable martingales with stationary, independent increments. Then $\langle X \rangle_t = t(EX_1^2), T \ge 0$.

Comment: What is $u_2$? What are your thoughts about the problem?

Comment: $\mathcal{u}_2$ should be a space of square integral martingales. Actually, I am not quite understand $t(EX_1^2)$.

Answer (score 0):

You have to see $E(X_{1}^2)$ like some kinda variance $\sigma^2$ for process. Standard brownian motion has variance 1, so its bracket process is 1*t.

That being said, depending on the tools you have there is two or three ways to solve this (One being really straightforward). 
Edit : Yes !  It is $t \cdot \sigma^2$ .

Comment: $t(EX_1^2) = t \cdot (EX_1^2)$?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fact that the quadratic variation is the unique a.s. continuous, monotone increasing and adapted process so that $⟨X⟩_0=0$ a.s. t that makes $X^2_t-⟨X⟩_t$ a martingale. This is precisely the definition of the quadratic variation and therefore if you can verify that this is a martingale you have shown that this is the quadratic variation.